# How to copy these list element to another list using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have list elements (more than one) like these:

```
<li id="menu-item-51604"><span class="dish-name">葡萄柚清心優多</span><span class="dish-price">25/35/50</span><span class="dish-description"></span><span class="dish-notes"></span></li>

<li id="menu-item-3144"><span class="dish-name">清心優多</span><span class="dish-price">25</span><span class="dish-description"></span><span class="dish-notes"></span></li>

<li id="menu-item-2154"><span class="dish-name">柚清心優多</span><span class="dish-price">35/50</span><span class="dish-description"></span><span class="dish-notes"></span></li>
```

I want to be able to copy the list element that I click to a list called `ul.check-items`.

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#menu-item-51604').click(function(){
    $(this).clone().removeAttr("id").appendTo('ul.check-items');
});
```

Based on your edited post:

```
$('#firstlist li').click(function(){
    $(this).clone().removeAttr("id").appendTo('ul.check-items');
});
```

where firstlist is the id of the list that you want to clone from.

Answer (score 0):

Well something like this would put a click handler on that li item specifically:

```
$("#menu-item-51604").click(function() {
   $("ul.check-items").append( $(this).clone() );
});
```

But presumably you want similar behaviour from every element in whatever list "menu-item_51604" belongs to, so try so:

```
$("#yourULidHere li").click(function() {
   $("ul.check-items").append( $(this).clone() );
});
```

Note that this will result in multiple elements with the same id, so really you should change or remove the id from the copy:

```
$("ul.check-items").append( $(this).clone().removeAttr("id") );
// OR
$("ul.check-items").append(
     $(this).clone().attr("id", function(i,oldVal) { return oldVal + "copy"; })
);
```

(That last line will also create multiple elements with the same "...copy" id if you keep clicking the same element, but it shows you one way to modify the id...)

Comment: Wouldn't that also clone the IDs?

Comment: @j08691 - Yep. I was just adding a bit about that at the same time you were commenting.